# Lua how to retrieve second value of key1 , aaa2

Tags: lua-table

```
tab1 = {key1="aaa1","aaa2",key2="bbb"}

print(tab1.key1(1)) fail
print(tab1.key1{1}) fail
print(tab1.key1.1) fail
```

I cant retrieve second value of key 1..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> note that you have not set any keys to "key1" !
> another note do you know how index and what table are?
> please read about them in lua doc.

it's just a normal table, you can use "next" or "pair", functions to print all values.

```
tab1 = {key1="aaa1","aaa2",key2="bbb"}
for key, value in next, tab1 do
print(key, value)
end
-- result:
-- [[
1   aaa2
key2    bbb
key1    aaa1
]]
```

if its a key then just use '.key1' or '["key"]'
or its not a key then by default it's an index.
eg:

```
print(tab1.key1) -- or tab1["key1"]
print(tab1[1])
print(tab1.key2) -- or tab1["key2"]
```

and if you want to save more than a key inside another key simple make another table inside that key.

```
tab1 = {
key1 = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
}
print(tab1.key1[1])
print(tab1.key1[2])
print(tab1.key1[3])
```

sorry if i did not explain it well enough.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I'm still trying to understand, but your method really works.